# Changing Spring containers log level setting

Tags: java, spring, logging, ioc-container

How do i change the log level of a spring container which does not run in an appserver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your `log4j.properties` (if using log4j):

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO
```

Comment: I am using spring 3.0.1 and i think it uses slf4j by default.

Comment: @java_geek yes, but slf4j needs an underlying framework and that is usually log4j

Comment: slf4j is a facade, and it will work if you set this in log4j.properties. It depends which logging you are using.