# spring batch admin disable logs

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have integrated spring batch admin with the existing spring web application. I can trigger/control the jobs using batch admin screen and am using Tomcat8 for deployment. Everything is working perfectly but Spring admin batch logs are triggering in the console causing catalina.out filling in GB. 
Sample logs as below:

```
DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing SQL query [SELECT distinct JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE order by JOB_NAME]
DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing SQL query [SELECT distinct JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE order by JOB_NAME]
DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL query
DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT COUNT(1) from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION E, BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE I where E.JOB_INSTANCE_ID=I.JOB_INSTANCE_ID and I.JOB_NAME=?]
```

and my log4j configuration as below:

```
<logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false" >
   <level value="WARN" />
   <appender-ref ref="DailyRollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.springframework.jdbc" additivity="false" >
   <level value="WARN" />
   <appender-ref ref="DailyRollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.web" additivity="false" >
   <level value="WARN" />
   <appender-ref ref="DailyRollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>   

<logger name="org.springframework.batch" additivity="false" >
   <level value="WARN" />
   <appender-ref ref="DailyRollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>

<logger name="org.springframework.batch.admin" additivity="false" >
   <level value="WARN" />
   <appender-ref ref="DailyRollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>
```

But i am getting the logs continuously. Can you please suggest how to disable/increase the log level? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created logback.xml as suggested by the following link and it works like charm!!

[Change Spring framework log level in simple example project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252743/change-spring-framework-log-level-in-simple-example-project/23254829#23254829][1])